# android MediaRecorder AudioSource from earphone

Tags: android, mediarecorder

now I have to use `MediaRecorder` to record even the file I play and my voice. However, when I use `earphone`, it will not record my file but can record my voice. Is there anyway to solve this problem? If there's any information insufficient, please tell me.

Below is my code of MediaRecorder:

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
recorder.setOutputFile(this.mOutputPath);
recorder.prepare();
```